# Move one flex-item move out from flex-container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this situation where I have to make one of the flex-item in a flex container take up all available space of parent (the flex container). Therefore, I moved other flex-items out of DOM by setting position to "absolute".

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
  <div style="flex:1 1 auto">Flex Item which should take it all...</div>
  <div style="position:absolute">Not really a Flex Item 1</div>
  <div style="position:absolute">Not really a Flex Item 1</div>
  <div style="position:absolute">Not really a Flex Item 2</div>
</div>
```

A little less hacky version of above:

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
  <div style="flex:1 1 auto">Flex Item which should take it all...</div>
  <div style="position:absolute">
     <div>Not really a Flex Item 1</div>
     <div>Not really a Flex Item 1</div>
     <div>Not really a Flex Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Constraints:**

- I cannot use `display:none` for those unwanted flex-items. They are actually pop-ups which are by default not visible but later become visible on some user actions.
- I cannot move those flex-items out of the flex-container for some other reasons.

Is there a more cleaner and elegant solution (possibly a flexbox based solution?) than using the `position: absolute`, keeping in view the mentioned constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `height: 0` or `width: 0`, you can hide the pop-ups without `position: absolute`, `display: none` or removing them from the container.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it the other way round: Let all the other elements still be flex-items and make that one element `position: absolute` with `height: 100%, width: 100%`

(You have to add `position: relative` to the container element for this to work)

```css
.x { 
background: red; 
position: relative;
}
.y { 
background: green; 
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column" class="x">
  <div style="flex:1 1 auto" class="y">Flex Item which should take it all...</div>
  <div>Not really a Flex Item 1</div>
  <div>Not really a Flex Item 1</div>
  <div>Not really a Flex Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting height or width to zero is contextually more cleaner solution so accepted Michael_B's answer. Thanks for writing your solution. :)

Comment: This worked for me, was banging my head because I set the position as sticky (to make the div stick at bottom) and changing it to absolute solved the issue.